# Devise session controller create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

I have create a session controller for the `devise` user login. At view the form is look like below

```
<%= form_tag new_member_session_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'user[email]' %>
    <%= password_field_tag 'user[password]' %>
    <%=  submit_tag 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

And in the controller I don't know about the `new`, `create` and `destroy` method please help me

```
class SessionController < ApplicationController
   def new
   end

   def create
   end

   def destroy
   end
end
```

Thank's

Comment: you should not need `SessionController` the devise rails engine automatically loads one (unless you need to customize the logic for some reason) did you use the devise generators to create the view?

Comment: Yes I use devise generates for views also I create registration controller for the adding extra field and I added it successfully I need to help in login form I need at username in place of email. I have also change in devise.rb file to make config.authentication_keys = [ :username ].

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your own views there are two options.  If you do not need custom controller logic (which you do not for simply changing the login field to username, as it's a config option), then you can use scoped views, like:

```
# in config/devise.rb
config.scoped_views = true
```

Which will trigger devise to look up views based on role, for example within `users/sessions`.

If you *do* need custom controller logic, you would make a controller that subclasses the appropriate devise controller (in your question you do not do this), then tell devise to use your controller.

```
# app/controllers/users/session_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end

# then in config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "users/sessions" }
```

Comment: Actually I want to use @username field in place of email.

Comment: that shouldn't affect the controller.  You can change that in `config/devise.rb` by setting `config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]`.

Comment: I make change in devise.rb file but it still show the email field at login form.

Comment: Are you sure devise is using your controller?  From the looks of things it seems unlikely that it is.  In the question your controller is not subclassing the devise controller, as I suggest, and as such should not work at all.  If you do not need custom controller logic, you don't need a controller at all, as devise provides the scoped views option for this.

Comment: If it's still showing the email on the form itself you need to change the route and edit the form you generated.  as stated in the answer, in config/routes.rb add `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }` THEN make sure that you've changed the form rails_root/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

Comment: also, in agreement with @numbers1311407 , you do not need a controller if you aren't overriding any actions